# How to make a Boxplot in R with the first and third quartiles Calculated by excluding the Median (odd number of data points)

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am a teacher and trying to make a boxplot in R match our "By Hand" calculations using a TI-83 or Ti-84.

The data is

```
myData<- data.frame(Year=c(1450, 1162, 1360, 1320, 1456, 1035, 1360,
                           1225, 1200, 1325, 1506, 1345, 1570, 1162, 
                            600, 776, 800))
```

The 5 number summary of this in a TI-83 comes from excluding the median when calculating the quartiles.

{ 600, 1098.5, 1320, 1405, 1570}

The 5-Number Summary (used by both boxplot() and the geom_boxplot() in ggplot2) is

```
> summary(myData$Year)

    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 

     600    1162    1320    1215    1360    1570
```

The discrepancy comes from a different style of calculating Q1 and Q3 (The TI calculator leaves out the median and the two R functions do not).

I would like either of the R boxplot functions to leave out the median so the two summaries match, and the resulting boxplot will look the same as doing it "by hand" from a TI-83.

(Keeping the cutoff for outliers still at 1.5*IQR from each quartile...There should be 1 outlier on the low side if the quartile method matches the TI-83. Both of those R functions result in a boxplot showing 3 outliers).

```
 ggplot(myData, aes(y=Year)) +
     geom_boxplot()
```

[image: Boxplot]

Suggestions?

Comment: You can feed your own values into `geom_boxplot`. See the help page where they show an example.

Comment: This doesn't work. You can specify the following aesthetics when you do that (lower, upper, middle, ymin, ymax ).....You can't manually determine where to show outliers when you use stat = "identity" in geom_boxplot. (unless I am missing something). Using this I cannot create the same boxplot that results if you find the quartiles leaving the median out (as a TI-83/84 does).

Comment: Can you update with the code you have tried? As you know, `ggplot` expects a dataframe but `myData` is a vector. Can you revise your question and make the problem reproducible.

Comment: Thank you. The code has been updated with the boxplot from geom_boxplot()